# Changed directory, wamp still goes to the old directory

Tags: windows, wamp, httpd

I needed to change the default `www` directory WAMP provides, changed it in `httpd.conf` modified `DocumentRoot`s as needed, works fine.
**But**, if I click on the wamp icon and click on "www directory", it will still go to the old directory. Is there any way to change this? (I restarted all services after changes, full functionality is provided)

I am just a bit afraid in the future development this might affect connections, so I want to fix it before anything unexpected appears and things go really bad.